# Test coverage for Index.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i recently starting working on react and created a react app using create-react-app . I have the below code in the index.js . I have to load different components based on Browser settings . For testing individual react components i used the react-testing-library and it worked fine but i am struggling to write a test case for this index.js file . Any pointers would be helpful .

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Component1 from './Components/Component1';
import Component2 from './Components/Component2';

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('Chrome') > -1) {
  ReactDOM.render( <Component 1/> , document.getElementById('app'));
} else {
  ReactDOM.render( <Component 2/> , document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using for testing? Include what you have tried and the issues you faced?

Comment: Thanks for the response . I have used react-testing-library as mentioned in the post . If it is functional component i used the render(<Component/>) from react testing library and asserted what i needed . The challenge i am facing on this index.js file is that how do i test the code . I cannot use the render(<component/>) since we are using ReacDOM.render method . Should i mock the ReactDOM.render method ? If yes , how should i load the index.js test file within the test case for loading different components .